# Convert a date string "yyyy-mm-dd" to milliseconds since epoch

Tags: r, date, format

I have some numbers that represent dates in milliseconds since epoch, 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970

```
    1365368400000,
    1365973200000,
    1366578000000
```

I'm converting them to date format:

```
    as.Date(as.POSIXct(my_dates/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT"))
```

answer:

```
 [1] "2013-04-07" "2013-04-14" "2013-04-21"
```

How to convert these strings back to milliseconds since epoch?

Comment: [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the date string at the `-`, subtract 1 from the month part (javascript month is zero based), call the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor with the parts (probably using `Date.UTC`), then call [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) of this new `Date` object to get the milliseconds since epoch. There are lots of example here on SO.

Comment: So this isn't a Javascript question? Milliseconds from epoch is not a purely Javascript concept. Would be best to remove the Javascript tag from the question and `R` from the title, as it is already a tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are your javascript dates

```
x <- c(1365368400000, 1365973200000, 1366578000000)
```

You can convert them to R dates more easily by dividing by the number of milliseconds in one day.

```
y <- as.Date(x / 86400000, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

To convert back, just convert to numeric and multiply by this number.

```
z <- as.numeric(y) * 86400000
```

Finally, check that the answer is what you started with.

```
stopifnot(identical(x, z))
```

As per the comment, you may sometimes get numerical rounding errors leading to `x` and `z` not being identical.  For numerical comparisons like this, use:

```
library(testthat)
expect_equal(x, z)
```

Comment: Richie Cotton, when I try to copy function as.Date(x / 86400000, origin = "1970-01-01") dates from console and add them to the vector manually and then apply function: as.numeric(y) * 86400000, I get not identical rezults. Maybe you know why? hier is my code: gyazo.com/b97add60821fdb801be112addc5db6f5

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a simple framework to handle various kinds of dates encoding and how to go back an forth. Using the R package ‘lubridate’ this is made very easy using the period and interval classes.

When dealing with days, it can be easy as one can use the as.numeric(Date) to get the number of dates since the epoch. To get any unit of time smaller than a day one can convert using the various factors (24 for hours, 24 * 60 for minutes, etc.) However, for months, the math can get a bit more tricky and thus I prefer in many instances to use this method.

`library(lubridate)
as.period(interval(start = epoch, end = Date), unit = 'month')@month`

This can be used for year, month, day, hour, minute, and smaller units through apply the factors.

Going the other way such as being given months since epoch:

`library(lubridate)
epoch %m+% as.period(Date, unit = 'months')`

I presented this approach with months as it might be the more complicated one. An advantage to using period and intervals is that it can be adjusted to any epoch and unit very easily.